# How do I filter a group of dictionaries so that I can extract values from one key based on whether *another* key meets certain conditions?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, data-extraction, key-value-coding

Amateur-to-intermediate Python programmer here.

I've got an Excel .csv that I'm attempting to extract some specific data from. I've already managed to extract the raw data into a list of dictionaries in Python. The data consists of about a dozen different keys (columns in the Excel sheet), but what I need involves the data in only two keys.

I want to extract the values of one key based on whether corresponding values in the *second* key meet certain requirements. The two keys are "UnitId" and "A5000 Overall satisfaction" (this is customer service related data), and I want to extract every UnitId value whose corresponding A5000 value is 5.

The problem is up until now, none of the functions I've tried for doing this manage to extract *anything*, and always yielded an empty dictionary or list (depending on the method I tried). My most recent function attempt gave me *some* progress, but the results don't contain all the data I desired.

I tried to simply extract every dictionary with an A5000 value of 5, hoping to work out extracting the UnitIds from there once I had narrowed down the list to the dictionaries I needed. But, instead of giving me all dictionaries with A5000 values of 5, it gave me all the keys of a *single* dictionary result whose A5000 value was 5.

**Here's the code I have from this most recent attempt**:

```
import csv

compiled_data = []
all_5_ratings = dict()
with open("C:\%%%%%%%%%%%\CW test file.csv") as CW_test_file:
#Here is the code I used to display the raw data in the console
    CWtest_dict = csv.DictReader(CW_test_file)
    for row in CWtest_dict:
        compiled_data.append(row)
    print(compiled_data)
    print("################################################")
#Here is my most recent attempted function to extract the desired data:
    for dict in compiled_data:
        for key, value in dict.items():
            if key == "A5000 Overall satisfaction" and value == "5":
                all_5_ratings.update(dict)
            else:
                pass
    print(all_5_ratings)
    #Below is a failed previous attempt
    all_fives = [x for x in compiled_data if x["A5000 Overall satisfaction"] >= "5"]
    print(all_fives)
```

Here is a [pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/NYqfDgKH) to a sample of compiled_data for reference (It's way too long to post here directly and the full thing is too big for free pastebin users):

And *here* is the result I get with my existing code:

```
{
    "VisitDate": "10/28/2021 21:58",
    "UnitId": "2",
    "A4000 Type of visit": "2",
    "A5000 Overall satisfaction": "5",
    "A6000 Likelihood to return": "5",
    "A7000 Likelihood to recommend": "5",
    "A8000 Value for Price": "5",
    "A9000 Friendliness of host/hostess": "5",
    "A10000 Wait time to be seated": "5",
    "A11000 Friendliness of server": "4",
    "A12000 Wait time for drinks": "5",
    "A13000 Wait time for food": "5",
    "A14000 Server's menu knowledge": "5"
}
```

Ultimately, my question is: How do I extract *all* UnitId values whose corresponding A5000 values are 5?

Comment: hmm, this is probably beside the point, but I have a slight issue with the fact that the local var `dict` is highlighted a different color than the other vars.

Comment: You should simplify your question to keep the minimal needed information. Also provide a **sample** of the input, as text, directly in the question.

Comment: Just create a reader with `reader = csv.reader(file)` and write `for row in reader:`, `if columnA5000 == 5:`, `data.append(culumnunitld)`. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I understood what you wanted to do. but this script puts all of the reviews where A5000 is 5 in a result array:

```
data = [{'VisitDate': '10/11/2021 11:26', 'UnitId': '23', 'A4000 Type of visit': '2', 'A5000 Overall satisfaction': '4', 'A6000 Likelihood to return': '5', 'A7000 Likelihood to recommend': '5', 'A8000 Value for Price': '5', 'A9000 Friendliness of host/hostess': '2', 'A10000 Wait time to be seated': '4', 'A11000 Friendliness of server': '5', 'A12000 Wait time for drinks': '4', 'A13000 Wait time for food': '5', "A14000 Server's menu knowledge": '3'}, {'VisitDate': '10/11/2021 11:27', 'UnitId': '14', 'A4000 Type of visit': '2', 'A5000 Overall satisfaction': '4', 'A6000 Likelihood to return': '4', 'A7000 Likelihood to recommend': '3', 'A8000 Value for Price': '3', 'A9000 Friendliness of host/hostess': '3', 'A10000 Wait time to be seated': '2', 'A11000 Friendliness of server': '2', 'A12000 Wait time for drinks': '4', 'A13000 Wait time for food': '4', "A14000 Server's menu knowledge": '3'}, {'VisitDate': '10/11/2021 11:38', 'UnitId': '22', 'A4000 Type of visit': '2', 'A5000 Overall satisfaction': '5', 'A6000 Likelihood to return': '5', 'A7000 Likelihood to recommend': '5', 'A8000 Value for Price': '5', 'A9000 Friendliness of host/hostess': '5', 'A10000 Wait time to be seated': '5', 'A11000 Friendliness of server': '5', 'A12000 Wait time for drinks': '5', 'A13000 Wait time for food': '5', "A14000 Server's menu knowledge": '5'}, {'VisitDate': '10/11/2021 11:52', 'UnitId': '11', 'A4000 Type of visit': '2', 'A5000 Overall satisfaction': '5', 'A6000 Likelihood to return': '4', 'A7000 Likelihood to recommend': '5', 'A8000 Value for Price': '5', 'A9000 Friendliness of host/hostess': '5', 'A10000 Wait time to be seated': '5', 'A11000 Friendliness of server': '5', 'A12000 Wait time for drinks': '5', 'A13000 Wait time for food': '4', "A14000 Server's menu knowledge": '5'}, {'VisitDate': '10/11/2021 12:02', 'UnitId': '14', 'A4000 Type of visit': '1', 'A5000 Overall satisfaction': '5', 'A6000 Likelihood to return': '5', 'A7000 Likelihood to recommend': '5', 'A8000 Value for Price': '5', 'A9000 Friendliness of host/hostess': '5', 'A10000 Wait time to be seated': '5', 'A11000 Friendliness of server': '5', 'A12000 Wait time for drinks': '5', 'A13000 Wait time for food': '5', "A14000 Server's menu knowledge": '5'}, {'VisitDate': '10/11/2021 12:09', 'UnitId': '18', 'A4000 Type of visit': '2', 'A5000 Overall satisfaction': '5', 'A6000 Likelihood to return': '5', 'A7000 Likelihood to recommend': '5', 'A8000 Value for Price': '5', 'A9000 Friendliness of host/hostess': '5', 'A10000 Wait time to be seated': '5', 'A11000 Friendliness of server': '5', 'A12000 Wait time for drinks': '5', 'A13000 Wait time for food': '5', "A14000 Server's menu knowledge": '5'}, {'VisitDate': '10/11/2021 12:11', 'UnitId': '23', 'A4000 Type of visit': '2', 'A5000 Overall satisfaction': '5', 'A6000 Likelihood to return': '5', 'A7000 Likelihood to recommend': '5', 'A8000 Value for Price': '5', 'A9000 Friendliness of host/hostess': '5', 'A10000 Wait time to be seated': '5', 'A11000 Friendliness of server': '5', 'A12000 Wait time for drinks': '5', 'A13000 Wait time for food': '5', "A14000 Server's menu knowledge": '5'}, {'VisitDate': '10/11/2021 12:12', 'UnitId': '23', 'A4000 Type of visit': '2', 'A5000 Overall satisfaction': '5', 'A6000 Likelihood to return': '5', 'A7000 Likelihood to recommend': '5', 'A8000 Value for Price': '5', 'A9000 Friendliness of host/hostess': '5', 'A10000 Wait time to be seated': '4', 'A11000 Friendliness of server': '3', 'A12000 Wait time for drinks': '5', 'A13000 Wait time for food': '4', "A14000 Server's menu knowledge": '4'}, {'VisitDate': '10/11/2021 12:17', 'UnitId': '14', 'A4000 Type of visit': '2', 'A5000 Overall satisfaction': '5', 'A6000 Likelihood to return': '5', 'A7000 Likelihood to recommend': '5', 'A8000 Value for Price': '5', 'A9000 Friendliness of host/hostess': '5', 'A10000 Wait time to be seated': '5', 'A11000 Friendliness of server': '5', 'A12000 Wait time for drinks': '5', 'A13000 Wait time for food': '5', "A14000 Server's menu knowledge": '5'}, {'VisitDate': '10/11/2021 12:27', 'UnitId': '23', 'A4000 Type of visit': '1', 'A5000 Overall satisfaction': '4', 'A6000 Likelihood to return': '3', 'A7000 Likelihood to recommend': '4', 'A8000 Value for Price': '3', 'A9000 Friendliness of host/hostess': '3', 'A10000 Wait time to be seated': '4', 'A11000 Friendliness of server': '2', 'A12000 Wait time for drinks': '3', 'A13000 Wait time for food': '4', "A14000 Server's menu knowledge": '3'}, {'VisitDate': '10/11/2021 12:31', 'UnitId': '1', 'A4000 Type of visit': '2', 'A5000 Overall satisfaction': '4', 'A6000 Likelihood to return': '5', 'A7000 Likelihood to recommend': '5', 'A8000 Value for Price': '4', 'A9000 Friendliness of host/hostess': '4', 'A10000 Wait time to be seated': '4', 'A11000 Friendliness of server': '5', 'A12000 Wait time for drinks': '4', 'A13000 Wait time for food': '4', "A14000 Server's menu knowledge": '3'}, {'VisitDate': '10/11/2021 12:34', 'UnitId': '1', 'A4000 Type of visit': '2', 'A5000 Overall satisfaction': '5', 'A6000 Likelihood to return': '5', 'A7000 Likelihood to recommend': '5', 'A8000 Value for Price': '4', 'A9000 Friendliness of host/hostess': '4', 'A10000 Wait time to be seated': '5', 'A11000 Friendliness of server': '5', 'A12000 Wait time for drinks': '5', 'A13000 Wait time for food': '4', "A14000 Server's menu knowledge": '3'}, {'VisitDate': '10/11/2021 12:39', 'UnitId': '18', 'A4000 Type of visit': '2', 'A5000 Overall satisfaction': '5', 'A6000 Likelihood to return': '5', 'A7000 Likelihood to recommend': '5', 'A8000 Value for Price': '5', 'A9000 Friendliness of host/hostess': '5', 'A10000 Wait time to be seated': '5', 'A11000 Friendliness of server': '5', 'A12000 Wait time for drinks': '5', 'A13000 Wait time for food': '4', "A14000 Server's menu knowledge": '4'}, {'VisitDate': '10/11/2021 12:41', 'UnitId': '11', 'A4000 Type of visit': '1', 'A5000 Overall satisfaction': '3', 'A6000 Likelihood to return': '4', 'A7000 Likelihood to recommend': '4', 'A8000 Value for Price': '4', 'A9000 Friendliness of host/hostess': '5', 'A10000 Wait time to be seated': '4', 'A11000 Friendliness of server': '5', 'A12000 Wait time for drinks': '4', 'A13000 Wait time for food': '4', "A14000 Server's menu knowledge": '3'}, {'VisitDate': '10/11/2021 12:44', 'UnitId': '17', 'A4000 Type of visit': '2', 'A5000 Overall satisfaction': '5', 'A6000 Likelihood to return': '5', 'A7000 Likelihood to recommend': '5', 'A8000 Value for Price': '4', 'A9000 Friendliness of host/hostess': '5', 'A10000 Wait time to be seated': '4', 'A11000 Friendliness of server': '4', 'A12000 Wait time for drinks': '5', 'A13000 Wait time for food': '5', "A14000 Server's menu knowledge": '4'}, {'VisitDate': '10/11/2021 12:49', 'UnitId': '2', 'A4000 Type of visit': '1', 'A5000 Overall satisfaction': '4', 'A6000 Likelihood to return': '5', 'A7000 Likelihood to recommend': '5', 'A8000 Value for Price': '5', 'A9000 Friendliness of host/hostess': '4', 'A10000 Wait time to be seated': '4', 'A11000 Friendliness of server': '4', 'A12000 Wait time for drinks': '5', 'A13000 Wait time for food': '5', "A14000 Server's menu knowledge": '4'}, {'VisitDate': '10/11/2021 12:49', 'UnitId': '17', 'A4000 Type of visit': '2', 'A5000 Overall satisfaction': '3', 'A6000 Likelihood to return': '4', 'A7000 Likelihood to recommend': '4', 'A8000 Value for Price': '4', 'A9000 Friendliness of host/hostess': '4', 'A10000 Wait time to be seated': '4', 'A11000 Friendliness of server': '4', 'A12000 Wait time for drinks': '3', 'A13000 Wait time for food': '5', "A14000 Server's menu knowledge": '3'}, {'VisitDate': '10/11/2021 12:54', 'UnitId': '17', 'A4000 Type of visit': '2', 'A5000 Overall satisfaction': '4', 'A6000 Likelihood to return': '4', 'A7000 Likelihood to recommend': '4', 'A8000 Value for Price': '4', 'A9000 Friendliness of host/hostess': '5', 'A10000 Wait time to be seated': '4', 'A11000 Friendliness of server': '5', 'A12000 Wait time for drinks': '4', 'A13000 Wait time for food': '4', "A14000 Server's menu knowledge": '3'}, {'VisitDate': '10/11/2021 12:59', 'UnitId': '18', 'A4000 Type of visit': '2', 'A5000 Overall satisfaction': '5', 'A6000 Likelihood to return': '5', 'A7000 Likelihood to recommend': '5', 'A8000 Value for Price': '4', 'A9000 Friendliness of host/hostess': '4', 'A10000 Wait time to be seated': '5', 'A11000 Friendliness of server': '4', 'A12000 Wait time for drinks': '5', 'A13000 Wait time for food': '4', "A14000 Server's menu knowledge": '4'}, {'VisitDate': '10/11/2021 13:00', 'UnitId': '18', 'A4000 Type of visit': '2', 'A5000 Overall satisfaction': '5', 'A6000 Likelihood to return': '5', 'A7000 Likelihood to recommend': '5', 'A8000 Value for Price': '5', 'A9000 Friendliness of host/hostess': '5', 'A10000 Wait time to be seated': '5', 'A11000 Friendliness of server': '5', 'A12000 Wait time for drinks': '5', 'A13000 Wait time for food': '5', "A14000 Server's menu knowledge": '5'}, {'VisitDate': '10/11/2021 13:19', 'UnitId': '1', 'A4000 Type of visit': '2', 'A5000 Overall satisfaction': '5', 'A6000 Likelihood to return': '5', 'A7000 Likelihood to recommend': '5', 'A8000 Value for Price': '5', 'A9000 Friendliness of host/hostess': '5', 'A10000 Wait time to be seated': '5', 'A11000 Friendliness of server': '5', 'A12000 Wait time for drinks': '5', 'A13000 Wait time for food': '4', "A14000 Server's menu knowledge": '5'}, {'VisitDate': '10/11/2021 13:23', 'UnitId': '14', 'A4000 Type of visit': '2', 'A5000 Overall satisfaction': '4', 'A6000 Likelihood to return': '4', 'A7000 Likelihood to recommend': '4', 'A8000 Value for Price': '4', 'A9000 Friendliness of host/hostess': '4', 'A10000 Wait time to be seated': '3', 'A11000 Friendliness of server': '3', 'A12000 Wait time for drinks': '4', 'A13000 Wait time for food': '3', "A14000 Server's menu knowledge": '1'}, {'VisitDate': '10/11/2021 13:36', 'UnitId': '2', 'A4000 Type of visit': '2', 'A5000 Overall satisfaction': '3', 'A6000 Likelihood to return': '4', 'A7000 Likelihood to recommend': '2', 'A8000 Value for Price': '3', 'A9000 Friendliness of host/hostess': '3', 'A10000 Wait time to be seated': '4', 'A11000 Friendliness of server': '4', 'A12000 Wait time for drinks': '3', 'A13000 Wait time for food': '4', "A14000 Server's menu knowledge": '4'}, {'VisitDate': '10/11/2021 13:37', 'UnitId': '18', 'A4000 Type of visit': '2', 'A5000 Overall satisfaction': '5', 'A6000 Likelihood to return': '5', 'A7000 Likelihood to recommend': '5', 'A8000 Value for Price': '5', 'A9000 Friendliness of host/hostess': '5', 'A10000 Wait time to be seated': '5', 'A11000 Friendliness of server': '5', 'A12000 Wait time for drinks': '5', 'A13000 Wait time for food': '5', "A14000 Server's menu knowledge": '5'}, {'VisitDate': '10/11/2021 13:38', 'UnitId': '2', 'A4000 Type of visit': '2', 'A5000 Overall satisfaction': '5', 'A6000 Likelihood to return': '5', 'A7000 Likelihood to recommend': '5', 'A8000 Value for Price': '4', 'A9000 Friendliness of host/hostess': '4', 'A10000 Wait time to be seated': '5', 'A11000 Friendliness of server': '5', 'A12000 Wait time for drinks': '5', 'A13000 Wait time for food': '4', "A14000 Server's menu knowledge": '5'}, {'VisitDate': '10/11/2021 13:41', 'UnitId': '16', 'A4000 Type of visit': '2', 'A5000 Overall satisfaction': '4', 'A6000 Likelihood to return': '4', 'A7000 Likelihood to recommend': '4', 'A8000 Value for Price': '3', 'A9000 Friendliness of host/hostess': '5', 'A10000 Wait time to be seated': '3', 'A11000 Friendliness of server': '4', 'A12000 Wait time for drinks': '4', 'A13000 Wait time for food': '5', "A14000 Server's menu knowledge": '2'}, {'VisitDate': '10/11/2021 13:45', 'UnitId': '21', 'A4000 Type of visit': '2', 'A5000 Overall satisfaction': '5', 'A6000 Likelihood to return': '5', 'A7000 Likelihood to recommend': '5', 'A8000 Value for Price': '5', 'A9000 Friendliness of host/hostess': '5', 'A10000 Wait time to be seated': '5', 'A11000 Friendliness of server': '5', 'A12000 Wait time for drinks': '5', 'A13000 Wait time for food': '5', "A14000 Server's menu knowledge": '4'}, {'VisitDate': '10/11/2021 13:55', 'UnitId': '16', 'A4000 Type of visit': '2', 'A5000 Overall satisfaction': '3', 'A6000 Likelihood to return': '5', 'A7000 Likelihood to recommend': '4', 'A8000 Value for Price': '3', 'A9000 Friendliness of host/hostess': '5', 'A10000 Wait time to be seated': '5', 'A11000 Friendliness of server': '5', 'A12000 Wait time for drinks': '3', 'A13000 Wait time for food': '5', "A14000 Server's menu knowledge": '5'}, {'VisitDate': '10/11/2021 14:07', 'UnitId': '23', 'A4000 Type of visit': '2', 'A5000 Overall satisfaction': '4', 'A6000 Likelihood to return': '4', 'A7000 Likelihood to recommend': '4', 'A8000 Value for Price': '4', 'A9000 Friendliness of host/hostess': '4', 'A10000 Wait time to be seated': '3', 'A11000 Friendliness of server': '3', 'A12000 Wait time for drinks': '4', 'A13000 Wait time for food': '4', "A14000 Server's menu knowledge": '3'}]
result = []
for row in data:
    if row['A5000 Overall satisfaction'] == '5':
        result.append(row)

print(result)
```

After re-reading the question, here is a version that puts the UnitId in an array where A5000 is 5

```
data = [{'VisitDate': '10/11/2021 11:26', 'UnitId': '23', 'A4000 Type of visit': '2', 'A5000 Overall satisfaction': '4', 'A6000 Likelihood to return': '5', 'A7000 Likelihood to recommend': '5', 'A8000 Value for Price': '5', 'A9000 Friendliness of host/hostess': '2', 'A10000 Wait time to be seated': '4', 'A11000 Friendliness of server': '5', 'A12000 Wait time for drinks': '4', 'A13000 Wait time for food': '5', "A14000 Server's menu knowledge": '3'}, {'VisitDate': '10/11/2021 11:27', 'UnitId': '14', 'A4000 Type of visit': '2', 'A5000 Overall satisfaction': '4', 'A6000 Likelihood to return': '4', 'A7000 Likelihood to recommend': '3', 'A8000 Value for Price': '3', 'A9000 Friendliness of host/hostess': '3', 'A10000 Wait time to be seated': '2', 'A11000 Friendliness of server': '2', 'A12000 Wait time for drinks': '4', 'A13000 Wait time for food': '4', "A14000 Server's menu knowledge": '3'}, {'VisitDate': '10/11/2021 11:38', 'UnitId': '22', 'A4000 Type of visit': '2', 'A5000 Overall satisfaction': '5', 'A6000 Likelihood to return': '5', 'A7000 Likelihood to recommend': '5', 'A8000 Value for Price': '5', 'A9000 Friendliness of host/hostess': '5', 'A10000 Wait time to be seated': '5', 'A11000 Friendliness of server': '5', 'A12000 Wait time for drinks': '5', 'A13000 Wait time for food': '5', "A14000 Server's menu knowledge": '5'}, {'VisitDate': '10/11/2021 11:52', 'UnitId': '11', 'A4000 Type of visit': '2', 'A5000 Overall satisfaction': '5', 'A6000 Likelihood to return': '4', 'A7000 Likelihood to recommend': '5', 'A8000 Value for Price': '5', 'A9000 Friendliness of host/hostess': '5', 'A10000 Wait time to be seated': '5', 'A11000 Friendliness of server': '5', 'A12000 Wait time for drinks': '5', 'A13000 Wait time for food': '4', "A14000 Server's menu knowledge": '5'}, {'VisitDate': '10/11/2021 12:02', 'UnitId': '14', 'A4000 Type of visit': '1', 'A5000 Overall satisfaction': '5', 'A6000 Likelihood to return': '5', 'A7000 Likelihood to recommend': '5', 'A8000 Value for Price': '5', 'A9000 Friendliness of host/hostess': '5', 'A10000 Wait time to be seated': '5', 'A11000 Friendliness of server': '5', 'A12000 Wait time for drinks': '5', 'A13000 Wait time for food': '5', "A14000 Server's menu knowledge": '5'}, {'VisitDate': '10/11/2021 12:09', 'UnitId': '18', 'A4000 Type of visit': '2', 'A5000 Overall satisfaction': '5', 'A6000 Likelihood to return': '5', 'A7000 Likelihood to recommend': '5', 'A8000 Value for Price': '5', 'A9000 Friendliness of host/hostess': '5', 'A10000 Wait time to be seated': '5', 'A11000 Friendliness of server': '5', 'A12000 Wait time for drinks': '5', 'A13000 Wait time for food': '5', "A14000 Server's menu knowledge": '5'}, {'VisitDate': '10/11/2021 12:11', 'UnitId': '23', 'A4000 Type of visit': '2', 'A5000 Overall satisfaction': '5', 'A6000 Likelihood to return': '5', 'A7000 Likelihood to recommend': '5', 'A8000 Value for Price': '5', 'A9000 Friendliness of host/hostess': '5', 'A10000 Wait time to be seated': '5', 'A11000 Friendliness of server': '5', 'A12000 Wait time for drinks': '5', 'A13000 Wait time for food': '5', "A14000 Server's menu knowledge": '5'}, {'VisitDate': '10/11/2021 12:12', 'UnitId': '23', 'A4000 Type of visit': '2', 'A5000 Overall satisfaction': '5', 'A6000 Likelihood to return': '5', 'A7000 Likelihood to recommend': '5', 'A8000 Value for Price': '5', 'A9000 Friendliness of host/hostess': '5', 'A10000 Wait time to be seated': '4', 'A11000 Friendliness of server': '3', 'A12000 Wait time for drinks': '5', 'A13000 Wait time for food': '4', "A14000 Server's menu knowledge": '4'}, {'VisitDate': '10/11/2021 12:17', 'UnitId': '14', 'A4000 Type of visit': '2', 'A5000 Overall satisfaction': '5', 'A6000 Likelihood to return': '5', 'A7000 Likelihood to recommend': '5', 'A8000 Value for Price': '5', 'A9000 Friendliness of host/hostess': '5', 'A10000 Wait time to be seated': '5', 'A11000 Friendliness of server': '5', 'A12000 Wait time for drinks': '5', 'A13000 Wait time for food': '5', "A14000 Server's menu knowledge": '5'}, {'VisitDate': '10/11/2021 12:27', 'UnitId': '23', 'A4000 Type of visit': '1', 'A5000 Overall satisfaction': '4', 'A6000 Likelihood to return': '3', 'A7000 Likelihood to recommend': '4', 'A8000 Value for Price': '3', 'A9000 Friendliness of host/hostess': '3', 'A10000 Wait time to be seated': '4', 'A11000 Friendliness of server': '2', 'A12000 Wait time for drinks': '3', 'A13000 Wait time for food': '4', "A14000 Server's menu knowledge": '3'}, {'VisitDate': '10/11/2021 12:31', 'UnitId': '1', 'A4000 Type of visit': '2', 'A5000 Overall satisfaction': '4', 'A6000 Likelihood to return': '5', 'A7000 Likelihood to recommend': '5', 'A8000 Value for Price': '4', 'A9000 Friendliness of host/hostess': '4', 'A10000 Wait time to be seated': '4', 'A11000 Friendliness of server': '5', 'A12000 Wait time for drinks': '4', 'A13000 Wait time for food': '4', "A14000 Server's menu knowledge": '3'}, {'VisitDate': '10/11/2021 12:34', 'UnitId': '1', 'A4000 Type of visit': '2', 'A5000 Overall satisfaction': '5', 'A6000 Likelihood to return': '5', 'A7000 Likelihood to recommend': '5', 'A8000 Value for Price': '4', 'A9000 Friendliness of host/hostess': '4', 'A10000 Wait time to be seated': '5', 'A11000 Friendliness of server': '5', 'A12000 Wait time for drinks': '5', 'A13000 Wait time for food': '4', "A14000 Server's menu knowledge": '3'}, {'VisitDate': '10/11/2021 12:39', 'UnitId': '18', 'A4000 Type of visit': '2', 'A5000 Overall satisfaction': '5', 'A6000 Likelihood to return': '5', 'A7000 Likelihood to recommend': '5', 'A8000 Value for Price': '5', 'A9000 Friendliness of host/hostess': '5', 'A10000 Wait time to be seated': '5', 'A11000 Friendliness of server': '5', 'A12000 Wait time for drinks': '5', 'A13000 Wait time for food': '4', "A14000 Server's menu knowledge": '4'}, {'VisitDate': '10/11/2021 12:41', 'UnitId': '11', 'A4000 Type of visit': '1', 'A5000 Overall satisfaction': '3', 'A6000 Likelihood to return': '4', 'A7000 Likelihood to recommend': '4', 'A8000 Value for Price': '4', 'A9000 Friendliness of host/hostess': '5', 'A10000 Wait time to be seated': '4', 'A11000 Friendliness of server': '5', 'A12000 Wait time for drinks': '4', 'A13000 Wait time for food': '4', "A14000 Server's menu knowledge": '3'}, {'VisitDate': '10/11/2021 12:44', 'UnitId': '17', 'A4000 Type of visit': '2', 'A5000 Overall satisfaction': '5', 'A6000 Likelihood to return': '5', 'A7000 Likelihood to recommend': '5', 'A8000 Value for Price': '4', 'A9000 Friendliness of host/hostess': '5', 'A10000 Wait time to be seated': '4', 'A11000 Friendliness of server': '4', 'A12000 Wait time for drinks': '5', 'A13000 Wait time for food': '5', "A14000 Server's menu knowledge": '4'}, {'VisitDate': '10/11/2021 12:49', 'UnitId': '2', 'A4000 Type of visit': '1', 'A5000 Overall satisfaction': '4', 'A6000 Likelihood to return': '5', 'A7000 Likelihood to recommend': '5', 'A8000 Value for Price': '5', 'A9000 Friendliness of host/hostess': '4', 'A10000 Wait time to be seated': '4', 'A11000 Friendliness of server': '4', 'A12000 Wait time for drinks': '5', 'A13000 Wait time for food': '5', "A14000 Server's menu knowledge": '4'}, {'VisitDate': '10/11/2021 12:49', 'UnitId': '17', 'A4000 Type of visit': '2', 'A5000 Overall satisfaction': '3', 'A6000 Likelihood to return': '4', 'A7000 Likelihood to recommend': '4', 'A8000 Value for Price': '4', 'A9000 Friendliness of host/hostess': '4', 'A10000 Wait time to be seated': '4', 'A11000 Friendliness of server': '4', 'A12000 Wait time for drinks': '3', 'A13000 Wait time for food': '5', "A14000 Server's menu knowledge": '3'}, {'VisitDate': '10/11/2021 12:54', 'UnitId': '17', 'A4000 Type of visit': '2', 'A5000 Overall satisfaction': '4', 'A6000 Likelihood to return': '4', 'A7000 Likelihood to recommend': '4', 'A8000 Value for Price': '4', 'A9000 Friendliness of host/hostess': '5', 'A10000 Wait time to be seated': '4', 'A11000 Friendliness of server': '5', 'A12000 Wait time for drinks': '4', 'A13000 Wait time for food': '4', "A14000 Server's menu knowledge": '3'}, {'VisitDate': '10/11/2021 12:59', 'UnitId': '18', 'A4000 Type of visit': '2', 'A5000 Overall satisfaction': '5', 'A6000 Likelihood to return': '5', 'A7000 Likelihood to recommend': '5', 'A8000 Value for Price': '4', 'A9000 Friendliness of host/hostess': '4', 'A10000 Wait time to be seated': '5', 'A11000 Friendliness of server': '4', 'A12000 Wait time for drinks': '5', 'A13000 Wait time for food': '4', "A14000 Server's menu knowledge": '4'}, {'VisitDate': '10/11/2021 13:00', 'UnitId': '18', 'A4000 Type of visit': '2', 'A5000 Overall satisfaction': '5', 'A6000 Likelihood to return': '5', 'A7000 Likelihood to recommend': '5', 'A8000 Value for Price': '5', 'A9000 Friendliness of host/hostess': '5', 'A10000 Wait time to be seated': '5', 'A11000 Friendliness of server': '5', 'A12000 Wait time for drinks': '5', 'A13000 Wait time for food': '5', "A14000 Server's menu knowledge": '5'}, {'VisitDate': '10/11/2021 13:19', 'UnitId': '1', 'A4000 Type of visit': '2', 'A5000 Overall satisfaction': '5', 'A6000 Likelihood to return': '5', 'A7000 Likelihood to recommend': '5', 'A8000 Value for Price': '5', 'A9000 Friendliness of host/hostess': '5', 'A10000 Wait time to be seated': '5', 'A11000 Friendliness of server': '5', 'A12000 Wait time for drinks': '5', 'A13000 Wait time for food': '4', "A14000 Server's menu knowledge": '5'}, {'VisitDate': '10/11/2021 13:23', 'UnitId': '14', 'A4000 Type of visit': '2', 'A5000 Overall satisfaction': '4', 'A6000 Likelihood to return': '4', 'A7000 Likelihood to recommend': '4', 'A8000 Value for Price': '4', 'A9000 Friendliness of host/hostess': '4', 'A10000 Wait time to be seated': '3', 'A11000 Friendliness of server': '3', 'A12000 Wait time for drinks': '4', 'A13000 Wait time for food': '3', "A14000 Server's menu knowledge": '1'}, {'VisitDate': '10/11/2021 13:36', 'UnitId': '2', 'A4000 Type of visit': '2', 'A5000 Overall satisfaction': '3', 'A6000 Likelihood to return': '4', 'A7000 Likelihood to recommend': '2', 'A8000 Value for Price': '3', 'A9000 Friendliness of host/hostess': '3', 'A10000 Wait time to be seated': '4', 'A11000 Friendliness of server': '4', 'A12000 Wait time for drinks': '3', 'A13000 Wait time for food': '4', "A14000 Server's menu knowledge": '4'}, {'VisitDate': '10/11/2021 13:37', 'UnitId': '18', 'A4000 Type of visit': '2', 'A5000 Overall satisfaction': '5', 'A6000 Likelihood to return': '5', 'A7000 Likelihood to recommend': '5', 'A8000 Value for Price': '5', 'A9000 Friendliness of host/hostess': '5', 'A10000 Wait time to be seated': '5', 'A11000 Friendliness of server': '5', 'A12000 Wait time for drinks': '5', 'A13000 Wait time for food': '5', "A14000 Server's menu knowledge": '5'}, {'VisitDate': '10/11/2021 13:38', 'UnitId': '2', 'A4000 Type of visit': '2', 'A5000 Overall satisfaction': '5', 'A6000 Likelihood to return': '5', 'A7000 Likelihood to recommend': '5', 'A8000 Value for Price': '4', 'A9000 Friendliness of host/hostess': '4', 'A10000 Wait time to be seated': '5', 'A11000 Friendliness of server': '5', 'A12000 Wait time for drinks': '5', 'A13000 Wait time for food': '4', "A14000 Server's menu knowledge": '5'}, {'VisitDate': '10/11/2021 13:41', 'UnitId': '16', 'A4000 Type of visit': '2', 'A5000 Overall satisfaction': '4', 'A6000 Likelihood to return': '4', 'A7000 Likelihood to recommend': '4', 'A8000 Value for Price': '3', 'A9000 Friendliness of host/hostess': '5', 'A10000 Wait time to be seated': '3', 'A11000 Friendliness of server': '4', 'A12000 Wait time for drinks': '4', 'A13000 Wait time for food': '5', "A14000 Server's menu knowledge": '2'}, {'VisitDate': '10/11/2021 13:45', 'UnitId': '21', 'A4000 Type of visit': '2', 'A5000 Overall satisfaction': '5', 'A6000 Likelihood to return': '5', 'A7000 Likelihood to recommend': '5', 'A8000 Value for Price': '5', 'A9000 Friendliness of host/hostess': '5', 'A10000 Wait time to be seated': '5', 'A11000 Friendliness of server': '5', 'A12000 Wait time for drinks': '5', 'A13000 Wait time for food': '5', "A14000 Server's menu knowledge": '4'}, {'VisitDate': '10/11/2021 13:55', 'UnitId': '16', 'A4000 Type of visit': '2', 'A5000 Overall satisfaction': '3', 'A6000 Likelihood to return': '5', 'A7000 Likelihood to recommend': '4', 'A8000 Value for Price': '3', 'A9000 Friendliness of host/hostess': '5', 'A10000 Wait time to be seated': '5', 'A11000 Friendliness of server': '5', 'A12000 Wait time for drinks': '3', 'A13000 Wait time for food': '5', "A14000 Server's menu knowledge": '5'}, {'VisitDate': '10/11/2021 14:07', 'UnitId': '23', 'A4000 Type of visit': '2', 'A5000 Overall satisfaction': '4', 'A6000 Likelihood to return': '4', 'A7000 Likelihood to recommend': '4', 'A8000 Value for Price': '4', 'A9000 Friendliness of host/hostess': '4', 'A10000 Wait time to be seated': '3', 'A11000 Friendliness of server': '3', 'A12000 Wait time for drinks': '4', 'A13000 Wait time for food': '4', "A14000 Server's menu knowledge": '3'}]
result = []
for row in data:
    if row['A5000 Overall satisfaction'] == '5':
        result.append(row["UnitId"])

print(result)
```

And here it is as a one liner:

```
result = [row['UnitId'] for row in data if row['A5000 Overall satisfaction'] == '5']
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you use a dictionary where a list is needed. `all_5_ratings.update(dict)` is overriding whatever previous entry you had. You could use a list and then 'append' instead of 'update' like you did when you first read in the data.